# Program executing twice after compilation

Tags: compilation, mingw

I have made a small test c++ file, called main.cpp in programmer's notepad.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

I use Mingw and compile using the windows cmd shell:

```
g++ -o Test main.cpp
```

The program compiles without errors and Test.exe is created. When I try to run it in de command shell it first opens a new command shell, runs the program, closes this new command shell and then runs the program again in the first command shell. 
The same happens when I browse to the folder and click the executable. It opens a command shell, runs the program, closes the command shell and does this again in a second command shell.

Does anybody have an idea of what could be going wrong here? Are my compiler setting wrong or something like that? I'm not very experienced with setting up compilers so it probably is something pretty basic.

Comment: This can't work fine for you because it misses "using namespace std;" . Where are you trying to execute the generated binary? In MSYS?

Comment: You're right. It was merely to show that I'm not doing anything fancy. I am using the standard windows cmd window. You think MSYS would improve results?

Comment: No. Please post the exact invocation command and its output, otherwise it will be hard for others to help you.

Comment: Ok, I have rephrased the question. Hope its clearer now.

Comment: Well...still too unclear, but it is most likely not your compiler, it looks like you are doing something else wrong. It could be anything and all, it is very unlikely that you'll find an answer to such a trivial question on here.

Comment: How do you start Test.exe? By typing `Test.exe` and pressing enter in the command shell?

Comment: I have tried several ways, by typing `Test`, `Test.exe` and clicking the executable in windows. All produce the same result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 runs project twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941918/visual-studio-2013-runs-project-twice)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had exactly the same problem and finally stumbled accross this post:
[Visual Studio 2013 runs project twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941918/visual-studio-2013-runs-project-twice)

so if you are using Avast as antivirus just disable deepscreen and your programs only run as often as you desire it ;)

/edit: any antivirus using cloud scan could cause this behaviour