# Visual Studio 2013 runs project twice

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64

When I press the "Local Windows Debugger" button when working on any basic C++ project in Visual Studio 2013, the console opens and the program outputs, but when the console closes, another console opens, the UI changes slightly and the program outputs again.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Create a new C++ project
   [image: enter image description her]
2. Inside the "Source Files" directory of the new project, create a file named "main.cpp"
3. Put a basic hello world program into the file:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
        cout << "Hello world!";
        cin.get();
    }
```

4. Save the code and press the "Local windows debugger" button on the toolbar
5. A console opens, and waits until you press enter

[image]

After the first console closes, a new one opens up, and the UI changes:
[image]

**Edit:**
Link to download a zip folder containing the project: [Test Project.zip](https://www.mediafire.com/?nnxd4hup2u25tpg)

Comment: I followed your steps and this does not happen to me.

Comment: Can you post the project being generated? The answer might be in the proj file itself.

Comment: I added a link to download a zip containing the project: https://www.mediafire.com/?nnxd4hup2u25tpg

Comment: This doesn't repro in my VS2013 using that project, plus the project looks fine. Does this only happen on Debug configuration? Does anything interesting pop out from "Debug" in the output window?

Comment: Just a small addendum: Threatfire (afaik no longer available as a standalone) causes massive slowdown of visual studio when starting projects.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had avast deepscreen enabled. To disable, goto avast user interface -> Settings -> Antivirus and uncheck the box that says "Enable Deepscreen"

[image]

Comment: Hmm. Now I remember that. I actually had this 6 months ago but forgot. I eventually uninstalled Avast because it had way too many false positives with executables and dlls that I build as a software developer who has projects that are 2 decades old..

Comment: Great answer @adventurerOK How did you figure out this was causing the problem?

Comment: Only Avast would consider running a virus twice.  Get rid of it completely, it is junk.

Comment: It runs unknown applications in a sandbox for a few seconds to determine if the application has any virus like behavior. If not the it will re run the application normally.

Comment: never thought I would find a solution to this problem, but this solves it. Who thought avast would do this?! Great Answer +1!

Answer (score 1):

On a new version of avast you need to uncheck CyberCapture option. To disable CyberCapture you need to open Avast->Settings->General and uncheck "Enable CyberCapture"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. 
Added exception to "c:\source\" where all my visual studio stuff is located.