# Visual Studio starts application two times (consecutively)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Every time I start my C++ application in Visual Studio 2013, it gets started twice before the debugger shows up.
If I for example try to debug my application, the following happens:

1. First the application starts.
2. After about 10 seconds it closes again.
3. Then the application gets restarted, but this time the debugger starts too.

I have no idea what could be causing this. Multiple projects are affected by this. I didn't change them. But strange enough, there's a project that doesn't suffer from this problem.

I have already tried repairing Visual Studio, but it didn't solve the problem.

Also:
The problem even occurs if I start the executable directly.

I hope you guys understand what I mean, because it is a really strange problem.

Comment: Turn off Avast Deep Scan or whatever it's called.

Comment: Regarding the Avast issue, these links may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941918/visual-studio-2013-runs-project-twice and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dc839484-de0e-47c0-b8dc-d240a1259a0c/why-does-my-console-open-twice-when-i-run?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: ARE YOU KIDDING ME?! That solved the problem! Thank you so much guys. And damn... even though I googled like crazy, I couldn't find that stackoverflow question that is basically a duplicate of mine...