# cygwin c++ program runs in separate cmd first then in cygwin terminal

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin

I just installed cygwin and am getting used to it, its using the terminal emulator mintty i believe.

Anyways when I run a simple cpp program I wrote and compiled it spawns a new cmd window and runs the program, when I close that the program runs again in the mintty terminal... Is there a way to prevent this?

EDIT:
I haven't touched the cygwin installation, i did install g++ through the cygwin setup however. Here is the program I am trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void Adder(){
    // Variables for state
    bool terminated = false; //Whether double zeroes have been entered
    int consecZeroes = 0; //Number of consecutive zeroes seen.
    int val;
    int subtotal = 0;
    int total = 0;

    // Loop and receive user input
    while(!terminated){
        cout << ">";
        cin >> val;
        // Check to make sure the val is a valid number
        if(!cin){
            cout << "Incorrect entry." << endl;
            terminated = true;
        }else{
            // Double zeroes: print total and exit
            if(val == 0 && consecZeroes == 1){
                cout << "Total " << total << endl;
                terminated = true;
            }
            // Single zero: print subtotal and reset to 0
            else if(val == 0 && consecZeroes == 0){
                cout << "Subtotal " << subtotal << endl;
                subtotal = 0;
                consecZeroes++;
            }
            // Add to subtotal
            else if(val != 0){
                consecZeroes = 0;
                subtotal = subtotal + val;
                total = total + val;
            }
            // Just in case
            else{
                cout << "Something went wrong." << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    Adder();

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it via cygwin with the command g++ -g -Wall -o out file.cpp. This produced out.exe. Running this with the command ./out.exe spawns a cmd console running the program, when i exit out of it the program is restarted in the mintty terminal.

Comment: Could you give more detail regarding what you did?

Comment: There's a remarkably similar problem that occurs with Visual Studio if you're using the Avast virus scanner and have Deepscreen enabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941918/visual-studio-2013-runs-project-twice

Comment: Extremely strange... I upvoted the question and Ross's link earlier, but if that's not relevant for you, as a long shot diagnostic you might try running the same program from Windows Explorer and/or a `cmd.exe` window, xterm or console window, and/or from another shell in case there's something bodgy in your shell setup.  You could also try putting a `std::cin.get()` or other "pause" in, then using Task Manager, sysinternals Process Explorer or similar to see what process is parent to the extra window.  Sysinternals `streams.exe -s -d .` might just clear some "untrusted code" flags.

Comment: Yup thanks Ross Ridge that solved it, I wonder why that happens?

Comment: From the sounds of things the virus scanner does some sort of test run on the executable before letting run normally.