# C# programs "run twice", both through the executable and through cmd

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

Here's my code just for reference, although I'm fairly sure that it isn't the code that's causing the issue. I've ran the identical code on other machines without the problem happening.

```
using System;

public class Program
{

public static void Main()
{
Console.WriteLine("Body-mass-index Calculator");

Console.Write("Enter a weight (in kg): ");
double weight = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter a height (in cm): ");
double heightcm = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

double heightm = heightcm/100;

double bmi = (weight/heightm/heightm);
double bmiformatted = Math.Round(bmi, 2);

Console.WriteLine("Resulting body mass index: {0}", bmiformatted);

}
}
```

When running through the executable, the cmd window opens up, I enter what it's asking me for, and the calculated bmi value is displayed. I then press enter, and the cmd window closes. So far so good. But then a second cmd window opens up, identical to the first, prompting me for values again. I'll do exactly what I did the first time, and it will close for good this time.

If I choose not to enter the values I'm prompted for, and instead close the window, it will again open the second window.

Running through cmd is a bit different. The program will run in a new window, and once that one is finished, it closes, and the program runs another time from the original cmd window.

If any additional information would help solve this issue, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It's not the code. Can you run it from the command-line, using its full name (including `.exe`), and see what happens? Maybe you have a rogue .bat file..

Comment: "Running through cmd is a bit different. The program will run in a new window, and once that one is finished, it closes, and the program runs another time from the original cmd window." The .bat thing might be worth checking out though, I remember following some convoluted setup instructions as part of the course at my university.

Comment: Yes, I read that. Did you run it as `program.exe`, or just `program`?

Comment: I ran it with the .exe included.

Comment: The other thing to check is your project properties in visual studio, on the Debug tab: is it set to "Start project" and not "Start external program"?

Comment: _Really_ hard to recreate, looks like the system gets into the habit of running twice :p

Comment: Talked to one of my TAs this morning about this, he suggested that it might be related to Windows 8.1. Can anyone running 8.1 confirm this? Incidentally, I have the same issue on both my desktop and laptop, both of which are on 8.1.

Comment: `wmic process get commandline, name, parentprocessid, processid /format:table` (or `format:list`) will dump command lines of programs running. What are the two command lines? And what are their parent processes.

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue too until I unchecked an option in avast! anti-virus.

Check to see if you have avast! anti-virus installed. If so, click on the gear icon on the left side for Settings -> Antivirus -> uncheck "Enable DeepScreen."

If it works, credit to adventurerOK who posted that solution (with screenshots) here:

[Visual Studio 2013 runs project twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941918/visual-studio-2013-runs-project-twice)

Answer (score -1):

You can also start in a debugger.

windbg or ntsd (ntsd is a console program and maybe installed). Both are also from Debugging Tools For Windows.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called **Symbols** in **C:**

Start *Windbg*. *File* menu - *Symbol File Path* and enter

```
srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

then

```
windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat
```

You can press **F12** to stop it and `kb` will show the call stack (`g` continues the program and `pct` runs to next function call). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.

Type `lm` to list loaded modules, `x *!*` to list the symbols and `bp symbolname` to set a breakpoint

If programming in VB6 then this environmental variable `link=/pdb:none` stores the symbols in the dll rather than seperate files. Make sure you compile the program with No Optimisations and tick the box for Create Symbolic Debug Info. Both on the Compile tab in the Project's Properties.

Also CoClassSyms (microsoft.com/msj/0399/hood/hood0399.aspx) can make symbols from type libraries.

### .